# Разбор предложения. Ошибки

Tags: стилистическая-ошибка

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, найти все ошибки в этом предложении. И корректно ли оно построено.

**Давно привык он к тому, что все называют его на "ты", к  своему
несерьезному имени и фамилии, которые когда-то так раздражали его,  привык
к вечному своему невезению, к выговорам, безденежью, к  тому,  что  друзья
забыли о нем.**

С большим уважением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно, но надо бы добавить еще один глагол "привык", так как предложения 1 и 2 связаны местоименной связью и образуют замкнутую структуру:

Давно привык он к **тому, что** все называют его на "ты", **привык** к своему несерьезному имени и фамилии, которые когда-то так раздражали его, привык к вечному своему невезению, к выговорам, безденежью, к тому, что друзья забыли о нем.

Comment: И что означает ваше выделение "**тому, что**"? Как это помогает понять якобы "нужность" еще одного глагола "привык"?

Comment: Понимаете, не хочется Вас лишний раз огорчать, но здесь тоже надо учитывать интонацию. С помощью интонации происходит членение сложного предложения на отдельные самостоятельные фрагменты с восходяще-нисходящей интонацией (они напоминают отдельные интонационно законченные предложения).  Перед пропущенным "привык"  идет понижение тона, далее следует второй фрагмент, который очень желательно начать с "привык".

Comment: Я ж понимаю... У врача ухо-горло-носа все болезни от ухо-горло-носа, а у стоматолога – от больных зубов. А у специалиста по интонации?..

Comment: Специалист по интонации к ней спокойно относится, а вот на других она может непредсказуемо воздействовать. Поди, всю ночь не спали.

Comment: Я пошутил. Вы не специалист по интонации. Вы специалист из простых вопросов делать сложные. Это называется "умствовать".

Comment: Ваше мнение обо мне, может быть, заинтересует модераторов, как Вы думаете? Обсуждайте ответы, а не отвечающих. А разговоры ни о чем - это на других форумах.