# Управление или согласование?

Tags: стилистическая-ошибка

Добрый день!

А в предложении ниже нет ошибки?

**Он привык к своему несерьезному имени и фамилии.**

Разве слово **фамилии** не должно управляться словосочетанием **к своему несерьезному**.

И какое правило при написании однородных членов.

Запутался. Помогите разрешить вопрос. Заранее спасибо

Comment: А в чем ошибка? Да еще "стилистическая"? Про правило - тоже не понял. Запятая тут не нужна по причине того, что союз И есть. А что еще за правило Вас интересует?

Comment: И да, не надо дублировать вопросы. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да нет, наверное. Хотя возможно и "к сво**им** несерьезн**ым** имени и фамилии".

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm

§195. Определение при существительных – однородных членах. Пункт 1.1

Comment: Ответ ссылается на статью в справочнике, где нет ничего похожего на рассмотренный пример.

Comment: *...над моим отцом и матерью.*
Это, разумеется, не аргумент. Вычитание яблок не имеет ничего общего с вычитанием апельсинов, сказал бы Винни-Пух. И г-н @Morkovkin.

Comment: я вас умоляю, у меня на заборе такой аргумент нарисован - мало не покажется, я ж его вам не приписываю. )))) Или вот здесь никому не приходит в голову доставать собеседника обращением в уродливой и противоестественной форме, но для Niemand'a это не аргумент (Или наоборот - аргумент). Если серьезно, понимаете, очень трудно рассуждать о том, что есть аргумент, если не определена тема вопроса. Если бы Вы потрудились сформулировать не только аргумент, но и сам тезис, может быть я Вас бы и понял.

Comment: Так что же, мать с отцом – аргумент или нет? А то слишком много букв пишете...

Comment: *Так что же, мать с отцом – аргумент или нет?* - "Кому и кобыла невеста".

Comment: Зря, г-н @Morkovkin. Ну, невнимательно прочитали, впредь внимательнее будьте. Там и другие "аргументы" имеются.

Comment: Врачу, исцелися сам.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55219/discussion-between-morkovkin-and-niemand).

Answer (score 2):

Расклад здесь такой:

1. Он привык к **своему** *несерьёз**ному** имени*;
2. *Он привык к **своей** несерьёз**ной** фамилии*;
3. *Он привык к **своим** несерьёз**ным** имени и фамилии*.

Comment: А на какой вопрос вы отвечаете, если не секрет? Понятно, что у вас допустимые варианты согласования по числу. Но у автора: "управление слов",  "не должно управляться словосочетанием" да еще "правило" какое-то. Кстати, №3 у вас - не лучший вариант. Во всяком случае - неоднозначный.

Comment: Пользователь Руслан, вероятно, неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Вариант №3 не является однозначно неправильным.)

Comment: ...привык к своему несерьезному имени и фамилии, которые когда-то так раздражали его...  несерьёзному..., которые (?)

Comment: Да я понимаю, что Вы считаете вопрос неправильно сформулированным, а как правильно-то? Судя по вашим ответам, вы считаете, что вопрос о согласовании по числу. Но это опять же догадка моя. Очень трудно рассуждать, базируясь исключительно на своих догадках о том, в чем состоит догадка другого.

Comment: (+) Судя по принятому ответу автору вообще все равно. Ну что ж, это его право. )))))

Comment: Судя по принятому ответу, г-н @Morkovkin, автор прочитал статью в справочнике.

Comment: @Niemand или просто ваш клон.)))) В статье-то нет ничего подходящего под ответ.

Comment: Г-н @Morkovkin, не производим.

Comment: @Niemand, а откуда знаете, что он "статью" прочитал?

Comment: Ниоткуда не знаю. Предполагаю, г-н @Morkovkin. Я же не Розенталь или Лопатин, чтобы мне верить на слово.

Comment: *Ниоткуда не знаю* замечательно. ))) С этого и надо было начинать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55190/discussion-between-morkovkin-and-niemand).

Comment: @МатвейДёмин к вам это не относится, но собственно, ответа я и не требовал.

Answer (score 1):

Если исходить из того, что вы спрашиваете о согласование по числу и роду прилагательного и однородных существительных (это никак **не** управление и **не** "словосочетанием"), то есть варианты.

Приблизительно так.

Если каждая из составляющих "несерьезна" сама по себе (имя - Акакий, фамилия - Семижопов), то нужно множественное *Он привык к своим несерьёзным имени и фамилии*.

Если несерьезно только само сочетание (У Достоевского - Лев Мышкин), то именно так, как у автора. ***Он привык к своему несерьезному имени и фамилии.*** Имя и фамилия тут - единое целое.

У Веллера (это же оттуда?) "Кеша Чижиков" скорее второй случай, чем первый. Так что выбор согласования оправдан.

**Но я не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, это всё Матвей Дёмин)))*.